# Does JavaScript check remaining conditions in “if”–“else if”–“else” after the first condition is true?

Tags: javascript, if-statement

In JavaScript, if you have an `if` … `else if` … `else` situation, does the computer keep checking the next condition if it previously triggered another condition? E.g. if the first `if` condition is true and the code executes, does it still attempt to check the conditions for `else if` or `else`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No it won’t check if the next condition is true, since you are using `else if`.

Instead, if you use `if` … `if` … `if`, then all `if` statement will be executed.

Answer (score 8):

Say you have a code segment

```
if(a)
  func1()

else if(b)
  func2()

else if(c)
 func3()

else
 func4();

//next statement
```

If `a` is true `func1()` will be called and, after it returns, the control will go to next statement.

Accordingly if `b` is true then the at first `func2()` will be called and then, after it returns, the control will go to next statement.

`func4()` will be called if `a`, `b`, `c` all of them are false. After `func4()` returns control goes to next statement.